# In iMovie 11, how do I export at my custom resolution/aspect ratio? It only allows 16:9/4:3?

Tags: video, quicktime, imovie, resolution

I see a few posts that say it will also export at the aspect ratio you imported at, but how?

I recorded a portion of my screen with Quicktime's screen recorder, and it came to a resolution of 680x812. I imported that into iMovie, as well as a 640x812 image at the end, but when I go to export, I only get this screen, where none of them are the resolution of my video, and it puts black letterboxing on the sides:

[image]

How do I do it?

Also, how do I get it to not degrade video quality?

Answer (score 4):

I can address your first question. You can't export into a custom resolution. For that, you need Final Cut Pro X and [Compressor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/compressor/id424390742?mt=12). See [this blog post](http://www.larryjordan.biz/fcpx-custom-project-sizes/) for a description of the process.

> (Apple's) suggestion was to edit your video using standard video formats in FCP X, then export it to Compressor and use the Geometry tab in Compressor to create the final movie size you need.